# Rails 6 Active Record - obtain unique/distinct results after using pg_search scope and a join?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg-search

I am struggling with an Active Record query in Rails 6 where I am joining 2 models that have a many-to-many relationship.

**Restaurant.rb (extract)**

```rb
 class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations: Cuisines
    has_many :restaurant_cuisines, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cuisines, through: :restaurant_cuisines

    # Associations (Location)
    belongs_to :location, foreign_key: 'location_name'
  
    # PgSearch setup
    include PgSearch::Model

    pg_search_scope :search_by_location,
      against: [:location_name],
      using: {
        tsearch: { prefix: true }
      }
 end
```

Location is a model in our app (and one of the elements that we want to search against for restaurants)

**Location.rb (extract)**

```rb
  class Location < ApplicationRecord
     self.primary_key = 'name' # Primary key for this table is name not id
    
     # Restaurant Assocation
     has_many :restaurants, foreign_key: "location_name"
  end
```

**Cuisine.rb (extract)**

```rb
  class Cuisine < ApplicationRecord
     # Associations: Restaurants
     has_many :restaurant_cuisines, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_cuisines
  end
```

I am trying to implement a combined search with filters, e.g.

- Search by restaurant location: text input that is passed into a pg_search scope
- Only for restaurants that have cuisines that match the filters
- Results are restaurants and only want to show unique restaurants as results

I thought that this result below should return 2 unique restaurants (based on test data) but it returns 0.

```
Restaurant.search_by_location('bali').joins(:cuisines).order('restaurants.id ASC').distinct
```

This is the output I see in the Rails console when I run this query

```
  Restaurant Load (0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN (SELECT "restaurants"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("restaurants"."location_name"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'bali' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank FROM "restaurants" WHERE ((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("restaurants"."location_name"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'bali' || ' ''' || ':*')))) AS pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35 ON "restaurants"."id" = pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35.pg_search_id INNER JOIN "restaurant_cuisines" ON "restaurant_cuisines"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" INNER JOIN "cuisines" ON "cuisines"."id" = "restaurant_cuisines"."cuisine_id" ORDER BY pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35.rank DESC, "restaurants"."id" ASC, restaurants.id ASC
  Restaurant Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN (SELECT "restaurants"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("restaurants"."location_name"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'bali' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank FROM "restaurants" WHERE ((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("restaurants"."location_name"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'bali' || ' ''' || ':*')))) AS pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35 ON "restaurants"."id" = pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35.pg_search_id INNER JOIN "restaurant_cuisines" ON "restaurant_cuisines"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" INNER JOIN "cuisines" ON "cuisines"."id" = "restaurant_cuisines"."cuisine_id" ORDER BY pg_search_0dbdc4fb0fbb8e199f1b35.rank DESC, "restaurants"."id" ASC, restaurants.id ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

If I remove the second half of the query then I get 4 results (2 restaurants that each have 2 cuisines)

```
Restaurant.joins(:cuisines).order('restaurants.id ASC')
```

And the first part of the query returns the 2 results in my seed

```
Restaurant.search_by_location('bali')
```

Combining these is where I get my error. Would appreciate any guidance on this issue.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO @TARAS REQUEST FOR DATA**

I created some sample data on which I would like to run these queries. My actual data has more columns but if the query works on this sample set I can extrapolate to the larger dataset.

**Restaurants**

```
Restaurant.all
  Restaurant Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"
=> [#<Restaurant:0x000056116c61fef8 id: 1, name: "la plancha", location: "bali", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:02:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:02:56 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61fd68 id: 2, name: "potato head", location: "bali", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:04 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:04 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61e1e8 id: 3, name: "milk", location: "bali", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:10 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:10 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61dea0 id: 4, name: "black sands", location: "bali", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:15 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:15 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61dd10 id: 5, name: "the forge", location: "bali", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:29 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:29 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61cd98 id: 6, name: "roast", location: "bangkok", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:37 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:37 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61cc08 id: 7, name: "% arabica", location: "bangkok", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:47 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:47 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61cb40 id: 8, name: "cocotte", location: "bangkok", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:53 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:53 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61c578 id: 9, name: "eat me", location: "bangkok", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:59 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:03:59 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Restaurant:0x000056116c61c438 id: 10, name: "kai", location: "bangkok", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:13 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:13 UTC +00:00>]
```

**Cuisines**

```
Cuisine.all
  Cuisine Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cuisines".* FROM "cuisines"
=> [#<Cuisine:0x00007f06247f2ed0 id: 2, name: "european", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:37 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:37 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Cuisine:0x00007f06247b3550 id: 3, name: "american", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:41 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:41 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Cuisine:0x00007f06247b3488 id: 4, name: "fusion", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:05:20 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:05:20 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Cuisine:0x00007f06247b3398 id: 1, name: "asian", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:04:27 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:05:42 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Cuisine:0x00007f06247b32a8 id: 5, name: "\ngrilled", created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:01 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:01 UTC +00:00>]
```

**RestaurantCuisines**

```
RestaurantCuisine.all
  RestaurantCuisine Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "restaurant_cuisines".* FROM "restaurant_cuisines"
=> [#<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f0624634eb8 id: 1, restaurant_id: 1, cuisine_id: 2, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:19 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:19 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c3420 id: 2, restaurant_id: 1, cuisine_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:23 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:23 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c3330 id: 3, restaurant_id: 2, cuisine_id: 3, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:28 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:28 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c3240 id: 4, restaurant_id: 2, cuisine_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:29 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:29 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c3150 id: 5, restaurant_id: 3, cuisine_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:34 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:34 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c3088 id: 6, restaurant_id: 3, cuisine_id: 2, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:36 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2fc0 id: 7, restaurant_id: 4, cuisine_id: 3, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:42 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:42 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2ef8 id: 8, restaurant_id: 4, cuisine_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:45 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:06:45 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2e30 id: 9, restaurant_id: 5, cuisine_id: 5, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:12 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:12 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2cf0 id: 10, restaurant_id: 5, cuisine_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:19 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:19 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2bd8 id: 11, restaurant_id: 6, cuisine_id: 2, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:31 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:31 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2ac0 id: 12, restaurant_id: 6, cuisine_id: 3, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:33 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:33 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2958 id: 13, restaurant_id: 7, cuisine_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:39 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:39 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c27c8 id: 14, restaurant_id: 7, cuisine_id: 5, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:40 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2638 id: 15, restaurant_id: 8, cuisine_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:44 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:44 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c24f8 id: 16, restaurant_id: 8, cuisine_id: 2, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:47 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:47 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c22a0 id: 17, restaurant_id: 9, cuisine_id: 3, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:51 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:51 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c2048 id: 18, restaurant_id: 9, cuisine_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:53 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:53 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c1e90 id: 19, restaurant_id: 10, cuisine_id: 5, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:59 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:07:59 UTC +00:00>,
 #<RestaurantCuisine:0x00007f06245c1d00 id: 20, restaurant_id: 10, cuisine_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:08:02 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:08:02 UTC +00:00>]
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data on which you are trying to do this

Comment: What does location_name hold? Is that expected to be (for example) "Bali"? 

If so then you don't need the complexity of the search method, which is preventing a result that is distinct on restaurant alone because it includes a ranking on how similar 'location_name' is to 'bali'.

Comment: @DavidAldridge

location_name will be a string with a city name like 'bali' or 'new york'. I added in some more detail to the question on location_name as this field is also the foreign key for the Location model (in case that matters).

Are you suggesting that rather than setting up the scope :search_by_location using pg_search that we use a WHERE condition with ILIKE. Something like

Restaurant.where("location_name ILIKE ?", "#{location]}%")

Where location could equal  'bali' / 'chicago' etc.

Comment: Yes, because pg_search returns an ordered set of likely matches which includes a "closeness" value in the select clause, which interferes with the DISTINCT operation. If you can identify the rows by location by other means so there is not a closeness match in the result, the DISTINCT operation will work.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - thanks that is helpful. We are using a similar search across a few models, i.e. not just Restaurant but also Items etc. For some of these other searches the pg_search we have set up is more complex and we couldn't simplify it down to a WHERE + ILIKE. Is there a way to get unique/distinct records where we retain pg_search?

Comment: Hmmm, well I think this would also do it: `Restaurant.where(id: Restaurant.search_by_location('bali')).joins(:cuisines).order('restaurants.id ASC').distinct`. Bit of a suboptimal query though.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - thanks that does produce the result set desired. Will implement ILIKE solution for the simpler searches.